Can I run Ubuntu on secure boot
I'm a windows 11 user and i want to run ubuntu (DUALBOOT). I'm not sure if i can boot on USB/run the ISO with secure boot. I have not run the ISO or booted it up yet.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't ask questions asking for opinions. You have to create the USB drive following the directions from the official Ubuntu site. If it does not work, provide details about your hardware and exact error messages (either copied and pasted, or as screenshots or pictures) in your question.

Ubuntu has supported installation with secure boot turned on for the past 12 years. We don't know what computer you have and the UEFI/BIOS it uses. Even if you edit your question and add this information, I probably haven't bought that computer and tried to install Ubuntu on it. So I guess it will work, but only you can tell for sure. If you use Windows 11 Pro and it has Bitlocker enabled by default, you will have to disable Bitlocker.

As already stated; if the Ubuntu ISO is written correctly as per documented procedures (and not reformatted during ISO write) it'll install on legacy/CSM hardware, on uEFI hardware with Secure-Boot enabled or disabled...   Key is writing the ISO to your installation media correctly; or as officially documented.

This question is similar to: How do I install Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@guiverc The answers in the linked How do I install Ubuntu? don't explicitly mention Secure Boot so not sure that is a similar quesrtion. Perhaps Secure Boot with Ubuntu is more applicable.

@ChesterGillon  I'm using my primary machine currently, and it has Secure boot enabled, but I'd install Ubuntu Desktop (and flavors) the same way I'd install it on an old legacy device (2005 HP Compaq, or 2008 Dell Optiplex etc) as secure boot makes no difference to the install, key (in my opinion) is just how the ISO is written to media, as that can prevent secure boot install from working (prevent boot loader from writing correctly).  Release & product can also matter (ie. valid or non-revoked key on media) but none of those specific details were mentioned by OP.  My 2c.

Some systems also have another setting in UEFI to allow USB boot as that may not be secure, but is separate from UEFI Secure boot settings. Also if you have nVidia or need other proprietary drivers you have to provide your own MOK or machine owner key to authorize a proprietary driver.

In most cases, you need to temporarily disable Secure Boot to boot from a bootable Ubuntu installation USB. Secure Boot is a security feature that restricts the system to boot only trusted, signed operating systems. By turning it off you're allowing the system to boot from unsigned media like a bootable Ubuntu USB.
Once you've successfully installed Ubuntu, remember to re-enable Secure Boot to maintain system security.
